# Android Studio new activity template with fragment inside

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

I noticed in the newer Android Studio versions, when I create a new activity, the template always puts a fragment inside, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

What's the benefit of doing this? I always have to delete the fragment, because it makes the code clutter. I know fragment is useful when you have multi-tab or master-detail structure. But why it's now embedded by default in every activities created?